# Use same JQuery function in differents pages with different parameters

Tags: jquery

I have a several pages which has the same ul (unordered list) with the same content, bur differents links:

```
<ul class='actions'>
    <li><a href='...'>1</a></li>
    <li><a href='...'>2</a></li>
    <li><a href='...'>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The thing is that I made a jquery function wich according to some parameters will delete or not some of the li elments.

My question is, if I have the same ul with the same class ("actions") in different pages, how can I configure differents parameters in my function.

I guess that I can put some hidden field in the page and get the parameters from there, but I think it is not the best approach..

Do you guys have a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: You can't call the function from the individual pages and pass parameters through?

Comment: There is too much information missing in this question.

Comment: i think that might be the answer he is looking for...

Comment: as mentioned on each new page load surely you could pass these elements into the jquery function on page load so for each page you pass in the require params  "function removeme(param1, param2){.."?

Comment: I can call the function on the page, but I want unobtrusive code it will be almost the same if I pass params when the page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Diodeus mentioned placing a not used class name in additon to what you currently have:

```
  <ul class='actions remove'>
      <li><a href='...'>1</a></li>
      <li><a href='...'>2</a></li>
      <li><a href='...'>3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

or as your not got an id then you could add an id or a data tag to the

```
  <ul class='action' id='removeme'>...</ul>

  <ul class='actions remove' data-rem='remove'>...</ul>
```

Depending what your removing and how

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a second class name on the element that you wish to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks at first I didn't get your idea but after see  how Simon explained it, it was very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<input type="hidden" value="somevalue" />` is a good approach.

If you don't like it you can still use the new HTML5 data attributes. Those attributes start with `data-` and it's only limited by your imagination and creativitation.

Example:

`<button data-id="100" id="delete-item">`.

Here's a good explanation of those attributes: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

If these actions are determined on page load you could use PHP to echo the needed parameter into the jQuery function prior to the page being rendered.